# count() results without using group by

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery

I am attempting something very similar to last example (Using GROUP BY) on this page:
https://thecodedeveloper.com/mysql-count-function/

Referring to the following table of data:

```
id   name   salary   department
 1   Tom    4000     Technology
 2   Sam    6000     Sales
 3   Bob    3000     Technology
 4   Alan   8000     Technology
 5   Jack   12000    Marketing
```

The following query:

```
SELECT department, COUNT(*) AS "Number of employees"
FROM employees
GROUP BY department;
```

Will produce the following output:

```
department    Number of employees
Marketing        1
Sales            1
Technology       3
```

Except I want to see the number of employees in each department as well as every user in the table.

So I want the output to look like this:

```
id   name   salary   department   employees per department
 1   Tom    4000     Technology        3
 2   Sam    6000     Sales             1
 3   Bob    3000     Technology        3
 4   Alan   8000     Technology        3
 5   Jack   12000    Marketing         1
```

I have managed to achieve what I want using a second query to test every result from the first query but it is extremely slow and I am convinced that there is a faster way to do it in a single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a window count. In MySQL 8.0:

```
select e.*, count(*) over(partition by d.department) as number_of_employees
from employees e
```

In earlier versions, an alternative uses a correlated subquery:

```
select e.*,
    (select count(*) from employees e1 where e1.department = e.department) as number_of_employees
from employees e
```

Comment: It is still quite slow though, is there anything I can do to speed it up?

Comment: I actually only need to know if there is more than one employee per department, can I limit the subquerry to 2? (I tried just putting LIMIT 2 at the end but i still counts more than 2 results!)

Comment: Please post TEXT of your most recent query. And TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT (yourquery); so we can see what the optimizer is doing with your query.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your support. I found that the mysql 8 version was nice and quick in my dev environment but unfortunately the server I am working on uses version 5.7 and the 5.7 method was pretty slow, it was slower than doing a second query on every result from the first.

Comment: I'll be honest with you, since the end of last week the feature I was working on has now been scrapped!!! For anyone else reading this question the mysql 8 answer above was the perfect solution (assuming you're using mysql 8!).